# JavaScript Regex for next 2 words after "at" isn't working

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let re = RegExp('/^(?<=at\s)[\w\W]*?(\w+\s\w+)$/g');
let regResults = re.exec(firstFarm);
```

What I am trying to do is get the 2 words after at but I keep getting null instead. The string is "Strawberries at Randall Farms". What's going wrong here?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/SnxGe7/1

Comment: Why not just `^.+at (.+)$` ?

Comment: @CodyＧ I can't do that because when I use that code it includes the "at" and the words before.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know it works in browser but it doesn't work when I use it in javascript

Comment: Ah, you must be unaware of matching groups.  `/^.+at (.+)$/mg.exec('Strawberries at Randall Farms')[1]` The parenthesis define a matching group, which can be easily extracted.

Comment: It doesn't work in my linked page either.  Read the explanations on the right-hand side of the page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So is the solution this ^(?<=at\s)*[\w\W]*?(\w+\s\w+)$ because I get * The preceding token is not quantifiable
this error when I try that for ecmascript(js) but it works for pcre. I think my js should support look behind but I'm not sure

Comment: a.mola's answer below seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Regex Editor](https://regex101.com/r/85bNDR/3)

```js
let str = "Strawberries at Randall Farms By Randall and Sons";
let regex = /(?:(?:^|\s)at\s)((?:\w+\s?){2})/i; // First 2 words after at
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]); // To get the matched words

let regex_2 = /(?:(?:^|\s)at\s)((?:\w+?\s?)+)/i; // All words after at
console.log(str.match(regex_2)[1]);
```

Comment: How can I modify this to get any words after the "at" ? So even if it is Randall Johnson Farms it still matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let firstFarm = "Strawberries at Randall Farms";
let re = RegExp('/(at(.*))/g');
let regResults = firstFarm.match(/(at(.+))$/g).toString().replace(/at /g, "").split(" "); // do not use split if you don't want an array
console.log(regResults); // this should print out Randall, Farms
```